Vuetify Sparkline label size cannot be less than 1
Why can't I make the label-size less than 1?  If I do, they disappear.  I can make them 1.0 or 1.5 but not 0.5.
https://play.vuetifyjs.com/#eNpVUNtugzAM/RUr2kMrcd0o3SJaad9R+pCVdERLSQSBdkP8+5xQKM2D49g+xyfn0JOmPoWfWgddywklmeEXLZnh+7wCyArRQWN+Jd/lRHW8Pkt19W8UWGtUTtwMTnV+U3Ju4CoKU+JkHOGZ2+OAZvWPFBWfagD0ogou/Y7J1tK7OyePfsnFd2ks3fuyLNkXohrxZ0FxgHsWPVzgTyqiIH70Zi2oZvoioCypDHWMCBDYQNXw0vdg88BJgmGALHyyxbGEi09NRtiadWI0L0T3MHsC47M51UKPI/ymVW2g4GfWSgP9SFMwwyis1rDbw+peA3BiKByS1zcPkiT1IN1uPNjEEYYPDKnNtml09EbIsHbJYBXMO8ngVa2ULhz/AWqXmVU=
I have looked at the source and the svg text element correctly has font-size="0.5" but is not visible.
I have tried making it 1.0 then looking at the source and editing it to 0.5 and that works fine!  Why can't Vuetify pass on the 0.5?
The API says it accepts a number or string, but em, vw and % do not work either.
    <template>
      <div style="overflow-x: auto">
        <v-sheet width="10000">
          <v-sparkline
            :model-value="value"
            height="18"
            label-size="1.0"
            line-width="0.1"
          >
            <template v-slot:label="item"> ${{ item.value }} </template>
          </v-sparkline>
        </v-sheet>
      </div>
    </template>
    
    <script>
      export default {
        data: () => ({
          value: [423, 446, 675, 510, 590, 610, 760],
        }),
      }
    </script>

